# How can I add titles to columns in a matrix that are created dynamically in a report?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a matrix that creates 3 columns when it's run and I am unable to add a title to those dynamically created columns, as required by the client, and can't find any fixes or examples online. I hoped putting the matrix and textboxes into a table might work, but the same result as the images below occurs. 
Is this seemingly simple thing just not possible, or is there a workaround I'm missing?

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdesg.png)

[Result Textbox displayed after columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27JGX.png)

[Row and Column Groups visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlaJ0.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you are trying to achieve, can you post what you are getting now and what you want it to look like. Also show column grouping details. Normally the columns are named based on the column grouping values.

Comment: Sure, I guess I could have been clearer; in the images I attached to the original question, the second image (Result Te..) is what I am getting when the report is run. "Col 2" is properly over the first 3 columns, and "Col 3" should be over the next 3 white columns that are created at run time, but instead it appears incorrectly after the matrix. This was designed improperly with 3 textboxs on top of the matrix (1st image (Design View). As I'm sure you know, If I added a title row inside the matrix, the title would repeat the same text over every three rows, but we need them to be different.

Comment: are there 3 NTLH1 values for each NTLH2 value?, If so then you should be able to use those value as the column headers  rather than typing to add them by hand. If this is the case then let me know and I'll put up an example of something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 3 MTLH1 value for each NTLH2 value then you can do something like this...
(as you supplied no sample data I generated some from the sample WideWorldImporters database). My Query gives me 5 columns and results similar to the below.

```
CustomerCategoryName  Qtr  Mnth  MnthName  OrderValue
Computer Store         1    1     Jan      10
Computer Store         1    2     Feb      12
Computer Store         1    3     Mar      15
Computer Store         2    4     Apr      20
Corporate              1    1     Jan      11
....
```

Basically we end up with 3 months per quarter

I then added a matrix control to the report, dragged `CustomerCategoryName` to the rows, `Mnth` to the Columns , `Qtr` above `Mnth` so it becomes a parent column and finally `OrderValue` to the data "cell".

I actually swapped the Mnth field out for MnthName in the column header to make it easier to read, but the column order is still sorted by Mnth (the numeric version). I then centered the column headers for readability.

The final design looks like this

[image]

If we run the report, the result looks like this..

[image]

As you can see we have 4 groups, one for each quarter, each with 3 columns.

If you want to customise the quarter names, you could do that if required by changing the expression in the cell. For example if we wanted all quarters to have "Q" preceeding the number except the 2nd Quarter whcih we want to have a specific string then you could use something like.

```
 =IIF(
    Fields!Qtr.Value = 2, 
    "Second Quarter",
    "Q" + Cstr(Fields!Qtr.Value)
    )
```

The final output now looks like this...

[image]

Alternatively, you could generate all the column headers in t-sql so where I have MnthName you could create a Quartername or similar.

Hopefully this is useful. If not, please post sample data and expected results of that sample data and I'll revise the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Alan! Also yes I realize now I handicapped you by not providing the values of NTLH “Not Touched in the Last Hour”; it returned a 0 or 1 BTW. The first set of three = 1 and second set = 0.. That being said your answer fits my real world issue perfectly, and I think will provide great help to many people searching for a very flexible solution!  Thank you again for creating a fantastic answer to a rather poorly designed question. :)

Comment: Glad to help. Just remember you can never provide too much info just boil your question down to focus on the real issue and then provide as much as you can. Sample data and expected results mean people on SO can build and test answers too.